# Unable to connect to CRX repository using the JCR API from Felix environment

Tags: osgi, jackrabbit, apache-felix, jcr, crx

I am trying to connect to CRX repository using JCR API. I followed the instruction at http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/RemoteAccess. If I write a plain java class and try to access the crx repository using

```
JcrUtils.getRepository("http://localhost:7402/crx/server");
```

it works perfect.
If I create it as bundle and deploy it in Felix, it does not work. I have put all the required dependencies in there.

Comment: What does 'does not work' mean? Do you have some sort of error message?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Jackrabbit standalone jar, you would be able to modify the nodes in the repository